# Set email for different domains

Tags: server, mail

I need to set up a mailserver. I've several different domains and I need to set up different emails for each other. 
 
For example: 
domain1.com -> user@domain1.com 
domain2.com -> user2@domain2.com

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to provide some more details, like the SMTP server you're using and so on.

Comment: You also need to provide more details on what is your final objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While waiting for more details, a very good point to start with could be the relevant webpages from the email server the user is running.

For example, both [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html) and [exim](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.20/doc/html/spec_43.html) (among the most used email servers in Ubuntu) have some documentation illustrating the concepts needed to host mutiple email domains.

The whole thing mainly boils down to configure local users to be mapped to specific email address(*es*).

Without any extra details, that's it.